# Get number of SMS notification

Tags: sms

Some services use SMS notifications. Examples would be Amazon and others for 2FA, some banks for TAN services and so on. Today I received an **phising attempt via SMS** for a bank account. It contained a shortlink (no, I didn't open it). I called the bank to notify them about those attempts and wanted to hand over the number, so they can try to take the account at its origin down. The **problem** was: I could not retrieve the number.

- The device runs on Android v10.
- Normally you can look up contact details by clicking on the senders name on top. This does not work for this kind of notifications.
- It's not a *Flash SMS*. It's stored in the inbox permanently.

*Note:* I know this question sounds basic, but neither me nor other colleagues I ask (who also work in tech), could find out *anything* about this … not even an approach to take. So I thought to ask at the collective brain of technology: StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Some SMS dont have number but only have header names like sms from google

You can google that header name to find source or since you have reported
banks contact ISP they will easily identify who sent you phishing msg to you